# document.getElementById(array[x]) returning null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call an element using an array index value but I keep getting a null message.

JS:

```
function img_disp() {
  var num = 0;
  var images_array = ["person_1","person_2","person_3","person_4","person_5","person_6","person_7","person_8","person_9","person_10","person_11","person_12"];
  document.getElementById(images_array[num]).style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

What can I do to make this work? I want to be able to call different ids using 1 function.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: Post a demo to reproduce the issue. As is, it looks fine. Are you sure the element exists when the script runs?

Comment: AHHH yeah I feel really stupid. The DOM wasn't loaded yet. Thanks a ton guys!

Answer (score 0):

You're not incrementing the variable `num`, You can use [loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to do it, eg:

```
function img_disp() {
    var images_array = ["person_1","person_2","person_3","person_4","person_5","person_6","person_7","person_8","person_9","person_10","person_11","person_12"];
    for(var num = 0; num < images_array.length; num++){
        document.getElementById(images_array[num]).style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

`img_disp()` It should be called when the DOM is loaded. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element), for know more about it.